# Efficiently move large number of files to different folder structure

Tags: python, windows, shutil, file-copying

I am trying to reorganize a large number of pdf files (3 million files, average file 300KB). Currently, the files are stored in randomly named folders, but I want to organize them by their file name. File names are 8-digit integers such as 12345678.pdf

Currently, the files are stored like this

```
/old/a/12345678.pdf 
/old/a/12345679.pdf 
/old/b/22345679.pdf
```

I want them to be stored like this

```
/new/12/345/12345678.pdf
/new/12/345/12345679.pdf
/new/22/345/22345679.pdf
```

I thought this was an easy task using shutil:

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

for path_old in Path('old').rglob('*.pdf'):
   r = int(path_old.stem)
   path_new = '/new/'+str(r// 1000**2)+'/'+str(r // 1000 % 1000)+'/'+path_old.name
   shutil.move(str(path_old),path_new)
```

Unfortunately, this takes forever. My script is only moving ~15 files per second, which means it will take days to complete.

I am not exactly sure whether this is a Python/shutil problem or a more general IO problem - sorry if I misplaced the question. I am open to any type of solution that makes this process faster.

Comment: If the files are on the same filesystem, use `os.rename()` instead of `shutil.move()`.

Comment: Checkout python `threading` module.

Comment: @AKX shutil.move literally calls os.rename so that shouldn't make any difference

Comment: Have you tried creating symbolic links instead?

Comment: @ViennaGuy After making some checks, e.g. if the file is a directory and so on. Cutting that extra call out will make a difference.